# Heartrate bump 10mins into exercise

Tags: running, heart-rate-monitor

Looking at the heart rate when running, there is usually a dramatic increase after about 10minutes. Dont think it is an effect of my equipment.

Does it have a name?[image: heart rate example]

Comment: Interesting, do you feel like you have to put in more effort around the ten minute mark? If you’re doing this outside, are you coming across a slight incline? Outside of those two things, the only thing I can personally imagine is that your body simply can’t maintain a lower heart rate any longer than 10 minutes. As in that’s all your current cardio endurance can handle.

Comment: This is on a treadmill. The breathing becomes more frequent from that point (No measurements to confirm it).

Comment: From the info given would have to agree with @JustSnilloc.  Assuming there are no underlying health problems / conditions - Rate of Perceived Exertion (RPE) would help a lot here.  http://www.sbfitnessmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Rate_of_Perceived_Exertion_Scale.jpg

How fast are you going?  What kind of shape are you in?  If you slow down does your HR return to normal........ Provide more info if possible.

Comment: What happens if you turn on Cadence? I know some (older) optical heartrate-monitors sometimes mix up cadence & HR after some time into a run.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the first 10 minutes are likely erroneous readings - it is not really conceivable for your heart rate to shoot up by 40bpm for no increase in effort after 10 minutes.
The steady increase in heart rate after this point is characteristic of cardiac drift - the increase in effort for maintained pace.

How do you measure your heart rate? Using a chest strap, a optical wrist sensor, or the contacts on a treadmill?
It is not uncommon for problems to arise with poor contact if using a chest strap (that's why it needs to be relatively tight, and lubricated to ensure it reads properly), with a watch being too loose if it has an optical sensor (not to mention if you have hairy/tattooed arms).

If you have any queries about using HR, don't hesitate to ask, as I've been using it as a training tool for a few years now.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it might be the case. I've been using optical wrist sensor since I started with threadmill.

Comment: My subjective experience during those initial 10 minutes is that the HR really is significantly lower and the rate of breaths required.

Comment: Yes, as you start your heart rate will be low - however it should rise very quickly to start before plateauing and then slowly drifting. I would expect the first spike to be a real reading, and that it should then curve to the 10 minute reading.

Comment: How tight do you have your watch? Other factors such as water, and light interference affect optical sensors.